# Buildozer build for Android fails with 'OS Error: [Errno socket error] [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED]

Tags: python, kivy, buildozer

Build environment: MacOS - Big Sur, both venv - virtual environment and non-venv, Python 3.9.2, trying to build APK file from a basic demo 'kivy' 2.0.0 script as a proof of concept.
Full error message:
File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 1309, in do_handshake
self._sslobj.do_handshake()
OSError: [Errno socket error] [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1108)